# Convert Html or RTF to Markdown or Wiki Compatible syntax?

Tags: c#, .net, api, markdown

Is there a .net api that can do this?  I saw [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) has a standalone exe that I could wrap but I'd rather not if there is something already out there.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here's the code I used to wrap [pandoc](http://code.google.com/p/pandoc/).  I haven't seen any other decent methods so far unfortunately.

```
public string Convert(string source)
{
    string processName = @"C:\Program Files\Pandoc\bin\pandoc.exe";
    string args = String.Format(@"-r html -t mediawiki");

    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(processName, args);

    psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;

    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo = psi;
    psi.UseShellExecute = false;
    p.Start();

    string outputString = "";
    byte[] inputBuffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
    p.StandardInput.BaseStream.Write(inputBuffer, 0, inputBuffer.Length);
    p.StandardInput.Close();

    p.WaitForExit(2000);
    using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(
                                           p.StandardOutput.BaseStream))
    {

        outputString = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }

    return outputString;
}
```

Comment: Two small changes: "ASCIIEncoding.UTF8" should be "Encoding.UTF8", and you can replace "Thread.Sleep(2000)" with "p.WaitForExit(2000)", which will return sooner if the process exits sooner.

Comment: Why `string args = String.Format(@"-r html -t mediawiki");` and not just `string args = "-r html -t mediawiki";`? Is there any intended side effect of String.Format that I'm missing?

Answer (score 14):

I have created a library [Html2Markdown](https://github.com/baynezy/Html2Markdown). Usage is very simple.

```
var markdown = new Converter().Convert(html);
```

Where `html` is the string representation of the HTML you wish to convert. I actively support it and happily accept contributions.