# Does MarkdownSharp allow inverse translation (HTML to Markdown)?

Tags: markdown, markdownsharp

The title is self-explaining.
I would like to translate my Markdown into HTML but also the inverse direction should be possible.
How to achieve this using `MarkdownSharp`?

In case there is no support for bidirection, what tool do you suggest me to use in repace of `MarkdownSharp` having these features?

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think markdownsharp can do it, but [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) certainly does.

[Convert Html or RTF to Markdown or Wiki Compatible syntax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6119793/convert-html-or-rtf-to-markdown-or-wiki-compatible-syntax) tells you how to wrap Pandoc in C#.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a native C# implementation I have created a library [Html2Markdown](https://github.com/baynezy/Html2Markdown). Usage is very simple.

```
var markdown = new Converter().Convert(html);
```

Where `html` is the string representation of the HTML you wish to convert. I actively support it and happily accept contributions.